# How to Reassign value of StringBuffer?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

How can we re assign the value of a StringBuffer or StringBuilder Variable?

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("teststr");
```

Now i have to change the value of sb to "testString" without emptying the contents.
I am looking at a method which can do this assignment directly without using separate memory allocation.I think we can do it only after emptying the contents.

Comment: Can you explain more of what is it that you want to achieve? And is it with `StringBuffer` particularly and you will not accept the newer, faster, better `StringBuilder` instead?

Comment: In Java the **assignment** operator is `=` and the **reassignment** term is usually applied to scope variables (e.g. `sb = new StringBuffer()`). So, generally speaking, your question is a bit incorrect, because the only answer you can get is `sb = new StringBuffer("testString")` -- you probably wouldn't ask a bountified question about such sort of things. And the phrase "without emptying the contents" brings total confusion. So please take your time to explain your goals better.

Comment: @polygenelubricants  StringBuilder is ok.But am looking for the method in StringBuilder to assign value later by using previous. memory location.

Comment: @cdb: see discussion section in my answer.

Comment: @cdb, please explain further your issue with using replace().

Comment: @Marcus Adams  No Issue in using replace other than its position arguments.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should first be mentioned that `StringBuilder` is generally preferred to `StringBuffer`. From [`StringBuffer`'s own  API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html):

> As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, `StringBuilder`. The `StringBuilder` class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization.

That said, I will stick to `StringBuffer` for the rest of the answer because that's what you're asking; everything that `StringBuffer` does, `StringBuilder` also... except synchronization, which is generally unneeded. So unless you're using the buffer in multiple threads, switching to `StringBuilder` is a simple task.

---

#### The question

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("teststr");
```

> "Now i have to change the value of `sb` to `"testString"` without emptying the contents"

So you want `sb` to have the `String` value `"testString"` in its buffer? There are many ways to do this, and I will list some of them to illustrate how to use the API.

---

The optimal solution: it performs the minimum edit from `"teststr"` to `"testString"`. It's impossible to do it any faster than this.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("teststr");
sb.setCharAt(4, 'S');
sb.append("ing");
assert sb.toString().equals("testString");
```

---

This needlessly overwrites `"tr"` with `"tr"`.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("teststr");
sb.replace(4, sb.length(), "String");
assert sb.toString().equals("testString");
```

---

This involves shifts due to `deleteCharAt` and `insert`.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("teststr");
sb.deleteCharAt(4);
sb.insert(4, 'S');
sb.append("ing");
assert sb.toString().equals("testString");
```

---

This is a bit different now: it doesn't magically know that it has `"teststr"` that it needs to edit to `"testString"`; it assumes only that the `StringBuffer` contains at least one occurrence of `"str"` somewhere, and that it needs to be replaced by `"String"`.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("strtest");
int idx = sb.indexOf("str");
sb.replace(idx, idx + 3, "String");
assert sb.toString().equals("Stringtest");
```

---

Let's say now that you want to replace *ALL* occurrences of `"str"` and replace it with `"String"`. A `StringBuffer` doesn't have this functionality built-in. You can try to do it yourself in the most efficient way possible, either in-place (probably with a 2-pass algorithm) or using a second `StringBuffer`, etc.

But instead I will use the `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` from `String`. This will be more than good enough in most cases, and is definitely a lot more clear and easier to maintain. It's linear in the length of the input string, so it's asymptotically optimal.

```
String before = "str1str2str3";
String after = before.replace("str", "String");
assert after.equals("String1String2String3");
```

---

#### Discussions

> "I am looking for the method to assign value later by using previous memory location"

The exact memory location shouldn't really be a concern for you; in fact, both `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer` will reallocate its internal buffer to different memory locations whenever necessary. The only way to prevent that would be to `ensureCapacity` (or set it through the constructor) so that its internal buffer will always be big enough and it would never need to be reallocated.

However, even if `StringBuffer` does reallocate its internal buffer once in a while, it should not be a problem in most cases. Most data structures that dynamically grows (`ArrayList`, `HashMap`, etc) do them in a way that preserves algorithmically optimal operations, taking advantage of cost amortization. I will not go through amortized analysis here, but unless you're doing real-time systems etc, this shouldn't be a problem for most applications.

Obviously I'm not aware of the specifics of your need, but there is a fear of premature optimization since you seem to be worrying about things that most people have the luxury of never having to worry about.

Comment: yes know its a kind of premature optimization but am asking this because this is a hot topic in interviews.

Comment: *"The exact memory location shouldn't really be a concern for you;"* -- true, but if a method took a parameter `void func(StringBuilder sb)` you might want to clear that exact parameter. `sb.setLength(0);` will do here, but `sb = new StringBuilder();` won't -- of course.

Comment: "The exact memory location shouldn't really be a concern for you": well, if I just reassign `StringBuilder` variable like this: `sb = new StringBuilder(newValue);` then I won't be able to pass this variable in lambda function because "variable must be final or effectively final".

Answer (score 29):

```
sb.setLength(0);
sb.append("testString");
```

Comment: @GreenieMeanie, ahah, I literally loled at your comment. Exactly my thoughts )

Answer (score 8):

What do you mean with "reassign"? You can empty the contents by using [`setLength()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength(int)) and then start appending new content, if that's what you mean.

**Edit**: For changing parts of the content, you can use [`replace()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)).

Generally, this kind of question can be easily answered by looking at the API doc of the classes in question.

Comment: Plus, I'm pretty sure `replace()` does a copy of the new string into StringBuilder storage. I don't think you can do this with no memory allocation.

Comment: @sblom: if the StringBuilder's underlying array is long enough to hold the replaced string, ther shouldn't be any allocation necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `StringBuilder` in place of a `StringBuffer`, which is typically what people do if they can (`StringBuilder` isn't synchronized so it is faster but not threadsafe). If you need to initialize the contents of one with the other, use the `toString()` method to get the string representation. To recycle an existing `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`, simply call `setLength(0)`.

**Edit**
You can overwrite a range of elements with the `replace()` function. To change the entire value to `newval`, you would use `buffer.replace(0,buffer.length(),newval)`. See also:

- [StringBuilder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [StringBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for the replace() method of the StringBuffer:

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("teststr");
sb.replace(0, sb.length() - 1, "newstr");
```

Internally, it removes the original string, then inserts the new string, but it may save you a step from this:

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("teststr");
sb.delete(0, sb.length() - 1);
sb.append("newstr");
```

Using setLength(0) reassigns a zero length StringBuffer to the variable, which, I guess, is not what you want:

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer("teststr");
// Reassign sb to a new, empty StringBuffer
sb.setLength(0);
sb.append("newstr");
```

Comment: It doesn't remove the original string! Check my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I think `replace()` is the best way. I checked the Java-Source code. It really overwrites the old characters.

Here is the source code from replace():

```
public AbstractStringBuffer replace(int start, int end, String str)
  {
    if (start < 0 || start > count || start > end)
      throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);

    int len = str.count;
    // Calculate the difference in 'count' after the replace.
    int delta = len - (end > count ? count : end) + start;
    ensureCapacity_unsynchronized(count + delta);

    if (delta != 0 && end < count)
      VMSystem.arraycopy(value, end, value, end + delta, count - end);

    str.getChars(0, len, value, start);
    count += delta;
    return this;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing entire value of StringBuffer:

```
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("word");
  sb.setLength(0); // setting its length to 0 for making the object empty
  sb.append("text");
```

This is how you can change the entire value of StringBuffer.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert to/from a String, as follows:

```
 StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
 buf.append("s1");
 buf.append("s2");

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(buf.toString());
 // Now sb, contains "s1s2" and you can further append to it
```